# About calculating a Random Color

Tags: c#, xna

I just started learning game programming at school and we are using c#(and xna. So now we need to make a tetris game. What I want to do is using random number to create the colors so Im wondering wether this is correct or not:

```
    public Block RandomColor()
    {
        int r = Random.Next(6);
        if (r == 0)
        {
            return Color.Red;
        }
        else if (r == 1)
        {
            return Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (r == 2)
        {
            return Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (r == 3)
        {
            return Color.Green;
        }
        else if (r==4)
        {
            return Color.Blue;
        }
        else if (r==5)
        {
            return Color.Indigo;
        }
        else if (r==6)
        {
            return Color.Purple;
        }
```

I am pretty uncertain about this because

1) visual studio doesnt give errors on this one

2) But everytime I want to write Color 2 things pop up: RandomColor and ConsoleColor. Do I need randomColor then instead of Color?

I tested wether I could screw with the code after Color. and the answer was yes. So does it mean the colors wont change when I run the code?

First time on stackoverflow so not sure Im doing this right:)

Comment: Your question is pretty good for a first try, and it is *hilarious* that you are worried when VS doesn't give you errors. Your third question is a bit confusing, what did you do and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Strange! It should give you errors. `Random.Next` is not a static method and it shouldn't compile. Also what is the `Block` type?

Comment: Another note is that Random.Next(6) will return a number in {0,1,2,3,4,5} so it will never be 6 and thus you will never get the Purple color.

Comment: So what happened was: instead of typing e.g. color.orange I typed color.justsomethingrandomhere and VS didnt pop an error which I found strange

Comment: I think you just forgot add "using" for Microsoft.Xna.Framework in your .cs file.Type "Color" and press Shift+Alt+F10 and compiler propose you add "using".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different method to get a random color from a set of colors:

```
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private Color[] Colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Orange, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Indigo, Color.Purple };

    public Color RandomColor()
    {
        return Colors[rnd.Next(Colors.Length)];
    }
```

Comment: i would change `new Random()` into `New Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode)` to be sure allways is random, because if you execute code few times in same milisecond (in some loop) it will show same random number. Random uses time to calculate numbers, and guid uses ticks...

Comment: Better use single Random object on whole game. I'll always create one in game class and pass it wherever it required. Also in this way if you want you can set to int same seed and reproduce whole game.

Answer (score 1):

A few things about your code:

1. You state a return type of `Block` but actually return `Color` objects. Pretty surprising the compiler isn't complaining about that.
2. Because you are returning `Color` objects (once you get (1) fixed) you are pretty good to go. `ConsoleColor` is not used in XNA (not even sure what "randomColor" is).
3. You can't just invoke `Random.Next`. You need to create a `Random` instance (**not** in this method, especially if it will be called in a loop) and then invoke `Next` on that.
4. Invoking `Next` returns a number in [0,x) (where x is the number passed). In case you aren't familiar with that notation, x is *exclusive* so you will never get x itself. Your if statements should range from 0 to 5, not 1 to 6.

Otherwise, assuming you are actually using the return value in `SpriteBatch.Draw` you are totally in the ballpark. Not having errors is a good thing :). Your second and third questions don't make a ton of sense yet.